# UITextView: Tapping a universal deep link that should lead to the SAME app, opens the fallback URL in Safari

Tags: ios, uitextfield, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I have a **Branch.io** universal deep link that displays a product page in my app, or the equivalent website page if the app is not installed.

When tapping the link from other apps such as WhatsApp or Notes, the link works. My app is launched and immediately displays the correct product.

However, if a user uses my own app's messaging platform to pass this link to another user as a text message, the message is displayed in my app using a **UITextView**, and tapping the link from this UITextView always launches the fallback URL in Safari.

Only when switching back from Safari to my app, the deep link handler is called and the link is then handled correctly.

I would like my app to handle its own deep links immediately even if they are tapped from within the app itself, without launching Safari. Does anyone knows how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Deep links are an incredibly important part of delivering a high quality user experience. With deep links, you can take users to the exact thing they clicked on or even offer a customised on-boarding experience.

You can auto-route within app without launching safari browser, please follow this link for detailed implementation:

https://docs.branch.io/deep-linking/routing/#option-3-use-branchs-easy-config-deep-link-routing

Feel free to write to support@branch.io in case you have other doubts.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have implemented the solution as described and it works good. However, this doesn't solve the problem. TextView hyperlinks that are created using the NSAttributesString "link" attribute, always launch Safari in order to handle the link. In iOS 13, Safari is launched and immediately prompts "Open in [App]?" which is OK, but seems silly since the user has already been in the app when the link was tapped. I will work around this by implementing the "Will Interact with URL" delegate call to detect my links and handle them separately.